# Store data in Redis Cache via Laravel 5.3 is not working

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

I just attached the `redis` driver to Laravel `cache`.

Config:

```
   'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'client' => 'predis',
        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
          'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
          'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
          'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
          'database' => 0,
          'read_write_timeout' => 60,
        ],
```

A basic one:

```
  Cache::store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 10);
  $val = Cache::get('bar');
  Log::Debug($val);`
```

It returns an empty string.
If I do:

```
  Cache::put('bar', 'baz', 10);
  $val = Cache::get('bar');
  Log::Debug($val);
```

It returns 'baz'. But If I delete the `put` method, at the next attempt it will return again the empty string.

CLI monitor:

`1505914946.350596 [0 127.0.0.1:39102] "SELECT" "0"
1505914946.351143 [0 127.0.0.1:39102] "SETEX" "laravel:bar" "600000" "s:3:\"baz\";"`

Where I get it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your default driver is not `redis`. For this reason, when you are calling `put()` or `get()` without specifying the `store()` you are putting and getting from your default store.

There are two ways you can solve this.

Either, make `redis` your default store (see `config/cache.php`). Then this:

```
Cache::put('bar', 'baz', 10);
$val = Cache::get('bar');
Log::Debug($val);
```

Will just work and you'll be accessing the `redis` store.

Or, specify the store when your putting **and** getting:

```
Cache::store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 10);
$val = Cache::store('redis')->get('bar');
Log::Debug($val);
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one doesn't work but If I specify the store when I get date it works. Cheers!

Comment: Sure thing. What is the value of your `default` in `config/cache.php`?

Comment: Is  `'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'redis')`

Comment: And in your `.env` what is `CACHE_DRIVER` set to?

Comment: Ah - `CACHE_DRIVER=array`

Comment: That's why the first isn't working for you. If you do want your default to be `redis`, change that and you won't have to specify the store.

Answer (score 1):

find `CACHE_DRIVER` in `.env`, then to edit it:

```php
CACHE_DRIVER=redis //the default is file
```